# How to show all my facebook 'likes' and the associated total of 'fans'?

Tags: php, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been testing a way to show all my facebook 'likes' and the associated amount of 'fans'. The code below works but is very...very...very slow, and i assume it is so slow because of the large number of queries that have to go through Facebook's api due to the foreach function. Is there a away to do the same thing as i do below, but with only one query (not using the foreach)?

```
require_once('src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '12345',
    'secret' => 'blablabla',
    'api' => '172737262',
    'cookie' => true,
));
$likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes');

foreach($likes[data] as $value){
$id = $value['id'];
$fans = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "select fan_count,name from page where page_id = $id;"
));

echo "$id - {$fans[0]['fan_count']} - {$value['name']}<br>";
unset($id,$fans);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Facebook APIs, but in general, when you're doing SQL queries, you don't want to query the database more often than you have to, because accessing the database is an expensive operation.

So instead of using a for loop with this query to select the fan count for each page id one at a time, over and over again,

```
'query' => "select fan_count,name from page where page_id = $id;"
```

you could possibly remove the query from the for loop and rewrite it  to select all the fan counts at once, in one query, using the IN SQL syntax, something like

```
$ids = "id1, id2, ... , idn";

// ...

'query' => "select fan_count,name from page where page_id in ($ids);"
```

Maybe that might work?

Comment: Yess, that works :) I tried that before, but stuck all values in an array that i fed into the IN SQL. But simply adding all values in a string, like you did, it works. It's still slow, but a whole lot faster than it was before. Thanks :)